# Vis.js / Moment.js - Timeline Labels

Tags: javascript, momentjs, vis.js

I'm having a problem with the label format of vis.js timeline. I want to display an excat time period of 1 hour and 30 minutes and the labels should only display the amount of minutes and seconds passed.

I configured the options like this:

```
let options = {
        autoResize: true,
        min: '2000-1-1 00:00:00',
        max: '2000-1-1 01:30:00',
        start: '2000-1-1 00:00:00',
        end: '2000-1-1 01:30:00',
        //zoomMax: 86399999,

        zoomMin: 18000,
        format: {
            minorLabels: {
                millisecond: '',
                second:     'mm:ss',
                minute:     'mm:ss',
                hour:       'mm:ss',
                weekday:    '',
                day:        '',
                week:       '',
                month:      '',
                year:       ''
              },
              majorLabels: {
                millisecond:'',
                second:     '',
                minute:     '',
                hour:       '',
                weekday:    '',
                day:        '',
                week:       '',
                month:      '',
                year:       ''
              }
        }
    };
```

As far as I understood it, vis.js calls for the labels (second, minute, hour, etc.) the moment().format() function from moment.js. Is it somehow possible in moment.js formatting to add the amount of hours (H) times 60 to the minutes (mm) value in an easy way?

In my current configuration it restarts at 00 minutes after 60 minutes:
[timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZKJa.png)

(And yes, I'm working on an application for soccer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the docs](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options) you can find option to customize date format via function:

> You can also use a function format for each label. The function accepts as arguments the date, scale and step in that order, and expects to return a string for the label.

Below you can find converted time to minutes:

```
format: {
  minorLabels: function (date, scale, step) { 
    var time = date.format("HH:mm");
    return moment.duration(time).asMinutes();
  },
  majorLabels: function (date, scale, step) { return "" }
}
```

[JSFiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/3dpy2ka0/)